# Using an Alias on a Subquery and then doing a LEFT JOIN with it in the ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

This MySQL SQL statement conveys what I'm attempting to do, but isn't valid:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT Thing FROM BigList) AS SomeThing
  LEFT JOIN thingDetail ON SomeThing = thingDetail.Thing
  -- other left joins follow
```

The problem is that in the ON clause, the alias isn't allowed.  And, removing the alias from the subquery produces an error the the alias is required. Very Catch-22.

I've found lots of examples online where the JOIN-part is a subquery and aliases do work there.  But I haven't found something that does the above.

If it's in the MySQL manual on Subqueries, I'm missing it.  What syntax should I be using to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the column name `thing` in `ON` clause. It should be like

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT Thing FROM BigList) AS SomeThing
  LEFT JOIN thingDetail ON SomeThing.Thing = thingDetail.Thing
```

Comment: Almost immediately after posting, it hit me that the the Aliased Table Name and the Column Name from that table name both needed to be present -- which was what I was trying to do.  In the "real" example that didn't make it to StackOverflow for clarity reasons I had (SELECT DISTICT foo FROM bar) AS foo ... thus contributing to the confusion.

Comment: @WaltStoneburner, that's alright ... keeps happening.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Thing FROM BigList) AS SomeThing
LEFT JOIN thingDetail ON SomeThing.Thing = thingDetail.Thing
-- other left joins follow
```

You were referring to the `table` alias instead of the `column` in the table.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was doing.  Rule to self, don't use the same alias for the column and the alias in your actual code.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have mixed up the "join" alias with the column alias. The `subselect` in joins is like it's own table, you could also select different columns from BigList, so `SomeThingTab` in my version is like a virtual on-the-fly table.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT Thing as SomeThing FROM BigList) AS SomeThingTab
  LEFT JOIN thingDetail ON SomeThingTab.SomeThing = thingDetail.Thing
```